# Dependency for gcc-7-locales is not resolving despite installing cpp-7

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, gcc, locale

I'm trying to set up my Ubuntu for wifi drivers by manually downloading the packages and installing them as suggested in [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?newreg=a200550771584628880e9f818c21ddfd).

However the dependency for gcc-7-locales is not resolving despite of installing the cpp-7 package successfully and rebooting.
The error message for this package is the above statement alone.
Is there any package version mismatch or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gcc-7-base gcc-7 cpp-7 gcc-7-locales # install dependencies of gcc-7-locales
```